# Eazfuscator.NET v3.3/.NET 4.0 - Error occurred during processing of input file.

Tags: eazfuscator

Eazfuscator.NET v3.3/.NET Framework 4.0 - I got the following error when I changed Target framework from 3.5 to 4.0. It compiles without errors with 3.5 framework.

Error occurred during processing of input file 'MyApp.exe' --> sn.exe: Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

I tried to delete files from AppData\Local\Temp, restarted computer and restarted VS2012 but no lock so far.

Please help.